# ccTLD (e.g. .it) instead of a gTLD (e.g. .com) for a multicountry AND multilang site

Tags: seo, multilingual, internationalization, country-specific, cctld

I use a ccTLD for my website and I want to use it as a gTLD.

Will Google punish me for using a ccTLD instead of a gTLD (e.g. .com) for a multicountry AND multilang site?

The URL structure I'm aiming for looks like this (examples):

```
mysite.it/ca/en => Italian TLD, Region/Country Canada, Language English
mysite.it/ca/fr => Italian TLD, Region/Country Canada, Language French
mysite.it/de => Italian TLD, Region/Country Germany, Language German
mysite.it/es => Italian TLD, Region/Country Spain, Language Spannish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: it will, at least initially.

### Long Answer: ccTLD is a very strong country-targeting signal and making Google understand otherwise will require work and patience.

You will need to employ everything at hand to neutralize the effect of using a ccTLD this way:

- Be extra careful with the implementation of hreflangs.
- Make sure that the content on each page is localized (not only translated) and consistent with your desired targeting.
- Put location information on relevant pages where appropriate.
- Build and maintain a healthy link profile from your target regions to relevant sections.
- Use NAPs such as Google My Business with local site link if applicable.
- Make sure to use a CDN for speed from any of the targeted regions.

*Note that you can't change the target region in Google Search Console when managing a ccTLD.*

**Despite all of the above it still might not have the effect of using a gTLD.** I have yet to find a case study showing a migration from a ccTLD used this way to a gTLD and the consequences for search visibility.

Google used to publish a [list of ccTLDs it treats as gTLDs](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-cctld-generics-16729.html) but has since [removed it](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-removes-cctlds-generic-tlds-25539.html).

More on [managing multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192) from Google's documentation.

*PS Note that you probably might want to alter your proposed URL structure to use language code and region targeting at the same time like so: mysite.it/ca-en.
This will save you from having to implement [x-default hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077#xdefault) on all the regional pages since **you can't use a country code only**.*

Comment: Great tips. The more I think about it the more it seems like a bad idea. So I just bought a new gTLD - this will solve my problems. Still have to migrate all my pages and content - luckily it's not a big site but still need to preserve link value for good SERP ranking - this will require some extra work.